# how to get values from google marker

Tags: javascript, maps

how do i get the values from my hard coded markers? i would like to get the value "**Ulas, Davao City**" Value and then place it on a div. anyone knows how to do this? thanks

my test site can be viewed here: http://wlocate.procreativelab.com/

```js
var markers = [
  
  
  {
        "title": 'SM City Davao',
        "lat": '7.0531937',
        "lng": '125.5817208',
        "description": 'SM City Davao : We got it all for you!',
  "icon": 'icon-truck.png'
    },
  
  {
        "title": 'San Pedro College Ulas',
        "lat": ' 7.0562176',
        "lng": '125.5394492',
        "description": 'Ulas, Davao City.',
  "icon": 'icon-car.png'
    },
 
 {
        "title": 'University of Mindanao Matina',
        "lat": '7.0717202',
        "lng": '125.5925354',
        "description": 'UM Matina.',
  "icon": 'icon-car.png',
    } 
      
    ];

    window.onload = function () {
        LoadMap();
    }
    function LoadMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   scrollwheel: false,
   zoomControl: false,
            scaleControl: true,
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    
    
    
  
        };
  
  
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

        //Create and open InfoWindow.
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i];
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title,
    icon: 'icon-car.png'
    
    
    
            });
 
            //Attach click event to the marker.
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    //Wrap the content inside an HTML DIV in order to set height and width of InfoWindow.
                    infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
   
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', LoadMap);
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', LoadMap)
        }
  
  
  
  
 }
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */
html,body,div,ul,ol,li,dl,dt,dd,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,p,blockquote,fieldset,input,hr {margin:0; padding:0;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,address,caption,cite,code,em,strong,th {font-size:1em; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal;}
ul,ol {list-style:none;}
fieldset,img,hr {border:none;}
caption,th {text-align:left;}
table {border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;}
td {vertical-align:top;}

html, body {
overflow-y:hidden;
 -ms-scroll-limit: 0 0 0 0;

}

body{
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}


.logo {
 background: url(../images/logo2.png) no-repeat;
 min-height: 37px;
 width: 300px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-left: 40px;
   

}

/* NAVIGATION */
nav {
  
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: -50px;
 
 


}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:after,
nav ul li a:before {
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #555;
}



/* SHIFT */
nav.shift ul li a {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;

}
nav.shift ul li a:hover {
  color: #91640F;
}
nav.shift ul li a:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  background: #F1C40F;
  visibility: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
nav.shift ul li a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}




.container {
 width: 100%; 
 background-color:black; 
 height: 100px
}

.footer{
 width:100%;
 background-color:black; 
 height:40px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#282828, #010101); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#282828,  #010101); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#282828, #010101); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#282828, #010101); /* Standard syntax */

}
 
.legends{
 position:relative;
}

.legends2{
 min-height: 20px;
 
 margin-top: 7px;
 border:#666 1px solid;
 border-radius: 5px;
 
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow:hidden;
 right:0;
 margin-right:100px;
 padding: 2px;
 
}

.legends3{
 min-height: 20px;
 
 margin-top: 7px;
 border:#666 1px solid;
 border-radius: 5px;
 
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow:hidden;
 right:0;
 margin-right: 75px;
 padding: 2px;
 
}


.legends4{
 min-height: 20px;
 
 margin-top: 7px;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow:hidden;
 right:0;
 margin-right: 5px;
 padding: 2px;
 
}



.slidingDiv {
 height:22px;
 padding-right: 3px;
 
 
}

.show_hide {
 display:none;

 
}



.slidingDiv2 {
 height:22px;
 margin-top: -22px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 5px;

 
 
}

.show_hide2 {
 display:none;
 padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
 
}


.slidingDiv3 {
 height:22px;
 margin-top: -22px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#fff;
 
 
 
}

.show_hide3 {
 display:none;
 padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 
}



.side{
 
 min-height: 200px;
 min-width: 300px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 overflow:hidden;
 right:0;
 
}

.clear{
 clear:both;
}







.accordion {
  width: 300px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  

}

.accordion .item .heading {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: #000 url('arrow.png') no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-position: right 20px top -95px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ec8484;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}





.accordion .item.open .heading,
.accordion .item:last-child .heading { border: 0; }

.accordion .item.open .heading { background-position: right 20px top -5px; }

.accordion .item .content {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-size: 14px;
}




.search{
 width: 250px;
 border: #2f2f2f 1px solid;
 height: 30px;
 background-color:#000;
 margin-left: 15px;
 
}


img.searchimg{
 
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-left: 2px;
}

.drop{
 position:absolute;
 margin-top: -20px;
 margin-left: 23px;
 font-size: 12px;
}



/* your custom CSS \*/
 @-moz-keyframes pulsate {
  from {
   -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
   opacity: 1.0;
  }
  95% {
   -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
   opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
   -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
   opacity: 0;
  }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  from {
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
   opacity: 1.0;
  }
  95% {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
   opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
   opacity: 0;
  }
 }
 /* get the container that's just outside the marker image, 
  which just happens to have our Marker title in it */
 #dvMap div.gmnoprint[title="I might be here"] {
  -moz-animation: pulsate 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  -webkit-animation: pulsate 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
  border:1pt solid #fff;
  /* make a circle */
  -moz-border-radius:51px;
  -webkit-border-radius:51px;
  border-radius:51px;
  /* multiply the shadows, inside and outside the circle */
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #06f, inset 0 0 5px #06f, inset 0 0 5px #06f, 0 0 5px #06f, 0 0 5px #06f, 0 0 5px #06f;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #06f, inset 0 0 5px #06f, inset 0 0 5px #06f, 0 0 5px #06f, 0 0 5px #06f, 0 0 5px #06f;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #06f, inset 0 0 5px #06f, inset 0 0 5px #06f, 0 0 5px #06f, 0 0 5px #06f, 0 0 5px #06f;
  /* set the ring's new dimension and re-center it */
  height:51px!important;
  margin:-18px 0 0 -18px;
  width:51px!important;
 }
 /* hide the superfluous marker image since it would expand and shrink with its containing element */
/* #map_canvas div[style*="987654"][title] img {*/
 #dvMap div.gmnoprint[title="I might be here"] img {
  display:none;
 }
 /* compensate for iPhone and Android devices with high DPI, add iPad media query */
 @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  #dvMap div.gmnoprint[title="I might be here"] {
   margin:-10px 0 0 -10px;
  }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WLocate Sample Site</title>
<style>
#dvMap {
   
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
    height: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
 max-width: 100%;
}

#dvMap iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
```